# Can you derive the public key from a PGP encrypted message without knowing the content of the message?

Tags: cryptography

I am working on a system to transfer short messages while obfuscating the intended recipient.

In essence, it combines many messages encrypted using PGP, and periodically publishes a file containing those messages.
The recipients would then download that file and try all messages against their secret key.

Given a message encrypted using PGP, could a potential attacker derive the public key from that message? And as such potentially gain information about the intended recipient?

This assumes that the public key is not published associated with personally identifiable information such as name or email address.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How is this related to mathematics?

Comment: This sort of question is probably more suitable for [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)